# How to display two horizontal line in same line with some sentence inbetween both using HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to display two horizontal lines in same line with a sentence inbetween those both.

my code,

```
<hr/> hello <hr/>
```

am getting output,

```
-------------------------------
hello
-------------------------------
```

my need,

```
------------ hello ----------
```

Comment: Instead of closing, how about moving to StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not work in all browsers, but here's a shot:

```
<table><tr><td style='width:33%'><hr/></td><td style='width:33%'>Hello.</td><td style='width:33%'><hr/></td></tr></table>
```